Visual Studio Code auto update last night and now my Django app crashes during startup
Yesterday my Django app ran on my VSC development server just fine. During the night VSC updated to version 1.92. This morning the app crashes before it even gets started.
Exception has occurred: RuntimeError
'cryptography' package is required for sha256_password or caching_sha2_password auth methods.
Internet search seems to indicate I need to load the Crypto package, but that does not make sense since the app ran fine yesterday. I checked my app against a CD backup copy from last week, it is identical NO changes. The check was performed using a program called axaris and it checked EVERYTHING in the app from images to code and libraries - everything is the same.
It might be the upgrade corrupted the crypto libary? Not sure. I don't want to start making changes to my ubuntu 20.4 machine before I gather more information.
Any suggestions?
I have tried to place some breakpoints to isolate the code causing the error but the error occurs VERY early just as the server is checking the code. I was performing a MYSQL search and once the query completed the error occured when I tried to use the result. I commented out the code and tried to start the app and it failed 5 lines down just after the very next query.
I checked the MYSQL server it seems fine. All the data is present no issues.
I then began checking some logs on my system and found that at midnight July 31st (last night) the VSC was updated to version 1.92.
This is either a BIG coincidence or I'm guessing the root of the problem.

Are u using virtualenv. Please share the actual error message, VS Code screen shot and package installed list for better understanding of issue.

Did you use a venv? If yes, is it activated? Can you run pip list to verify the package is installed?

Yes I am using a python VENV.

Yes, since the project worked the day before I assumed the crypto package was installed but the pip list confirms that it is. Ver 2.8

Yes the venv is active.

This is the exect spot of the crash. The code is from the _auth.py file from my Django project . The system is not finding the cryptography package.
def sha2_rsa_encrypt(password, salt, public_key):
"""Encrypt password with salt and public_key.
Used for sha256_password and caching_sha2_password.
"""
if not _have_cryptography:
    raise RuntimeError(


...I need to load the Crypto package... No, that is wrong, like the error says, you need the cryptography package, it's not the same as the Crypto package. Again, run pip list and see if cryptography is listed.

After doing some searching, the error appears to be coming from the pymysql package.
